# Which part of the given sentence has an error and why?

Tags: errors

Below is the sentence divided into four parts, indicated as (a), (b), (c), (d):

> (a) Another baffling change    (b)that I notice in him    (c) nowadays
>   is that he    (d) avoids to speak to me.

Answer (score 1):

"Avoid" takes gerund phrases as objects, not *to*-infinitive phrases, so (d) should be "avoids speaking to me." There are no rules that I know of that determine whether verbs take gerunds or infinitives as objects, unfortunately—you just have to learn each case.